# Segmentation error in C when trying to concatenate a string and char

Tags: c, arrays, string, cs50, string-literals

I keep getting a segmentation error when I try to add a character to the string test.  I have tried multiple iterations and can't figure out why I get the error.  I tried having the test set to `\0`.  I can't figure out how I am accessing outside test.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <crypt.h>

//this intializes the argument count and argument vector
int main(int argc, string argv[]) {
    //this makes sure it is a string
    if (argv[1] != NULL) {
        //this makes sure that the user typed 2 arguments, 
        //  the second being the keyword
        if (argc != 2) {
            printf("no hash inputed\n");
            return 1;
        }

        //main program once the keyword has been verified
        int h_len = strlen(argv[1]); 
        string hash = argv[1];
        string test = "A";
        int p_len = 0;
        printf("H len is %i and P len is %i\n", h_len, p_len);
        printf("%s and test: %s\n", hash, test);

        //this will iterate through the 1st space and test the charachters
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {

            //iterates through the characters that can be used in the  password
            //for (int i = A; i < z; i++)
            //for (char ch = 'A' ; ch <= 'z' ; ch == 'Z' ? ch = 'a' : ++ch )
            for (char i = 'A'; i <= 'z'; i++) {
                //this skips the ASCII inbetween Z and a
                if (i > 'Z' && i < 'a') {
                    i = 'a';
                }
                printf("%c", i); 
                //test[j] = test[j] + (char)i;
                test = strncat(test, &i, 1);
                printf("  test is %s\n", test);
                ...
```

Comment: You need to check `argc` _before_ you access `argv[1]`.

Comment: You have allocated one character for test.. and then tried to append to it.

Comment: The code has `//this makes sure that the user typed 2 arguments`. These will be in `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` unless you enclose them in quotes such as `"one two"`, when they will be passed to the same argument. But the code has `if ( argc != 2)` which is testing for only one **user** argument - the first is the executable's name.

Answer (score 4):

In this declaration

```
string test = "A";
```

there is declared the pointer `test` to the string literal `"A"`. You may not change string literals.

According to the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals)

> 7 It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
>   elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to
>   modify such an array, the behavior is undefined**

However in this statement

```
test = strncat(test, &i,1);
```

there is an attempt to modify the string literal pointed to by the pointer `test`.

You should declare a character array that has enough space to store additional characters.

Moreover if you are using the function `strncat` to copy `n` characters from the source string you should reserve memory in the destination array for `n + 1` characters because the function always appends the terminating zero.

That is (The C Standard, 7.23.3.2 The strncat function, footnote 302)

> 302) Thus, the maximum number of characters that can end up in the
>   array pointed to by s1 is strlen(s1)+n+1.

Comment: @chux To make it clear I appended the answer with a footnote from the Standard.:)

Comment: That footnote not only added clarity here, but caused me to review various posts I've made over the years obliging 3 updates - sigh.

Comment: @chux: yes, `strncat()` is much more palatable than `strncpy()`. It actually a decent way to implement a truncating string copy: `char dest[10] = ""; strncat(dest, src, sizeof(dest) - 1);`

Comment: True,  `char dest[N]; dest[0] = 0; strncat(dest, src, sizeof dest - 1);` has minor benefit of 1) less unneeded initialization with large N 2) Explicit `dest[0] = '\0';` useful for learners.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in this horrible cs50, `string` is defined as `char *`, so `string test = "A";` is equivalent to `char *test = "A";` which will make test point to a constant string of length 1 plus a null!

So even if it would be long enough to concatenate anything, you can't because it is read-only, and even if it was not read-only, you can't because it is not long enough.

Answer (score 0):

You have a string with one character in it (test="A") so it has a length of 2 (A + null char) and are trying to append other characters to it, so it WILL access outside of test.

Comment: Incomplete answer. `test` points to a string literal: attempting to modify it has undefined behavior anyway.

Answer (score -1):

everything is wrong here

<s>you cant strcat char * and the address of the char as you never know if there is zero after that character.</s> Your string is too short to accomodate anything longer than one character string. Next - you try to do something with RO memory as your `test` points to the string literal.

Buy a good book about C

Comment: `strncat` works if you pass 1 doesn't need null-terminator. And the string is too short but mostly it's a pointer not an array so segfault whatever the size

Comment: yeah I thought that is strcat

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: more precisely, it ihas undefined behavior because it points to a *string literal*.

Comment: Both are UB's so actually it does not matter. I can't say which UB is more bad. Both have to be corrected.

Comment: I was referring to the *it's a pointer not an array* part of JF's comment, which seems irrelevant. The OP's code has multiple counts of UB, which of course do not cancel each other ;-)